# How to create branch with zero previous commits?

Tags: git, github

I'm messing with git branches. When I create a new branch using this command `git checkout -b todo` then do specific changes and `commit` + `pull request`. When I want to create another `git checkout -b todo-other` branch to work on something else and apply `commit`+`pull request`, I find previous commits from the `todo` branch combined with the new `commits` inside `todo-other` `pull request.`

I want when I do my `pull request` from `todo-other` branch I find only the new `commits` I do in this branch. How can I manage this?

Comment: Your new `todo-other` branch is likely created at the same commit as the `todo` branch. You need to checkout the base branch (`master`?) first, *then* create the second branch.

Comment: Did you mean `git checkout master` then `git checkout -b other`? or `git switch master` then `git checkout -b other`.

Comment: Do you want to create a pull request based on master without the work from `todo`, or do you want to create a pull request that goes back into `todo`?

Comment: @NickMcCurd, I want to create a pull request based on `todo-other` branch without having previous `commits` that I did in `todo` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked specifically for a branch that has *no* previous commits, but this is not what you want.

More precisely, *most* branches *share* most of their commits with most other branches.

It helps most people to *draw a graph of commits*.  The reason for this is that in Git, each commit remembers its previous or *parent* commit.  This makes commits, as found by branches, be long sequences or chains, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- branch1
               \
                I <-J <-K   <-- branch2
```

Each commit has a unique hash ID.  (These uppercase letters stand in for the actual hash IDs, which you see in `git log` output but which are too big and ugly for humans to work with.)

The commits themselves have these hash IDs.  *Branch names*, like `branch1` or `branch2`, remember *one* hash ID, and that's the particular one commit to which the name points, but the commit itself remembers the hash ID of its parent.  So by using the *name* `branch1`, we—or Git—can quickly find commit `H`.  But from commit `H`, Git can work backwards to commit `G`, and then to commit `F`, and so on.

Typically, we might have a series of commits on branch `master` that end in some specific hash `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

From this, we might create two feature branches.  We actually start by creating both feature branches as *also* identifying commit `H` directly:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, feature1, feature2
```

We then tell Git that we'd like to *use* the name `feature1`, using `git checkout` or (since Git 2.23) `git switch`.  We can draw the result like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, feature1 (HEAD), feature2
```

Then we make a new commit in the usual way (edit files, `git add`, run `git commit`).  Git makes a new commit and gives it a new, unique hash ID—a new big ugly number—but we'll just call it `I`:

```
          I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, feature2
```

Git updates the *name* that the special name `HEAD` is attached-to.  In this case that's `feature1`.  So the name `feature1` now points to new commit `I`.  The two names `feature2` and `master` still point to commit `H`.

If we make a second commit on `feature1`, Git updates the *name* to point to the new commit:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, feature2
```

If we now run `git checkout feature2` or `git switch feature2`, Git will take `HEAD` off `feature1` and attach it to `feature2` instead.  We'll be working with the contents from commit `H` again:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, feature2 (HEAD)
```

If we now make two new commits `K` and `L`, we end up with:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

If we send either or both of these two branches to another Git, such as one on GitHub, and open review requests, the review requests will seem to have only commits `I-J` for `feature1`, and only `K-L` for `feature2`.  But in fact, commits up through `H` are now on *all three* branches.  GitHub just shows us those that are on the pull request **and** *aren't* on the "base branch" (`master`).

So, what you want is to tell Git that your new branch, whatever it is called, is to be created using the commit identified by some other name—perhaps `master`, but perhaps even better, `origin/master` or `origin/develop`.  As you suggested, you can use:

> ... `git checkout master` then `git checkout -b other` ...

or the equivalent with `git switch`.  You can shorten this somewhat using:

```
git checkout -b other master
```

or:

```
git switch -c other master
```

(but again you might want to use `origin/master` here, if your `master` has fallen behind).

Comment: Thank you @torek.I appreciate your time for writing this answer. It removes the ugly cloud from my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `git checkout -b` will start from the `HEAD`, meaning the current branch, which in this case in `todos`.

You can force a specific branch as the base by appending it to the command:

```
git checkout -b todo-other master
```